# performing actions depending on user role laravel

Tags: laravel, api

`users` table has a foreign key `role_id`, `roles` table contains `name` field, seeded Moderator and Client. I am developing an api, I have `TicketController`, and only clients should be able create them. Now store in `TicketController` looks like:

```
public function store(Request $request) : TicketResource
{
    $ticket = new Ticket();

    $ticket->title = $request->title;
    $ticket->desciption = $request->description;
    $ticket->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $ticket->department_id = $request->department_id;

    $ticket->save;

    return new TicketResource($ticket);
}
```

Route in `api.php` is

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('tickets', 'Api\TicketController@store');
});
```

Comment: its called authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating an API I would highly suggest using Passport. It's a bit overwhelming at first to use but it's very powerful. One of the features it has is "scopes" which allow you to limit actions for users based on the scopes they have been given.

With scopes you can give different users different scopes based on the user role. Then in your routes you can do things like this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'scopes:can-store'] ], function(){
    Route::post('tickets', 'Api\TicketController@store');
});
```

You can even keep it simple and name the scope the user role

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'scopes:editor,admin'] ], function(){
    Route::post('tickets', 'Api\TicketController@store');
});
```

Take a look at the [documentation so you can see how scopes work here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#token-scopes).